# Adding name to the user model in Asp.Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to add the functionality to edit a user's name in Identity, manage account.

This is my ApplicationUser-model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the default, scaffolded code for updating the profile information (currently, only phone number) (in `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/index.cshtml.cs`):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Could not find user ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }

    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
    if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
    {
        var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
        if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"An error occured while registering the phone number for user ID '{userId}'.");
        }
    }

    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    StatusMessage = "Your profile was updated";
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

I have added `FirstName` and `LastName` in the appropriate places:

The input model (code-behind):

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The input form:

```
<form id="profile-form" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Username"></label>
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" disabled />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button id="update-profile-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="fas fa-save"></span>
        Lagre
    </button>
</form>
```

How would I go about to add the ability to change `FirstName` and `LastName` in the same operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update `LoadAsync` method for loading/showing the properties :

```
private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    Username = userName;

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,            
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName
    };
}
```

And update `OnPostAsync` method to update `FirstName` and `LastName` properties:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }

    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
    if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
    {
        var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
        if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting phone number for user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }
    }
    if (Input.FirstName != user.FirstName)
    {
        user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
    }

    if (Input.LastName != user.LastName)
    {
        user.LastName = Input.LastName;
    }

    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Also don't forget to run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` to update database to include the new columns .